# Schema ._id not the same as ._id returned with .find()? [NodeJS/Mongoose]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm currently trying to learn NodeJS with MongoDB. I'm using mongoose to connect to a local installed version of MongoDB and am using mocha for my TTD.

I know the solution for this case, but not the reason why it is this way.

**Let me explain:**
I create a schema and a model called `MarioCharacter`.
I save this `MarioCharacter` to MongoDB using the `.save` function of mongoose.
I want to find this MarioCharacter (there's only one, its variable is "`newCharacter`") in the database using it's id.

My code with mongoose and mocha looks like this:

```
  //Find a record by its ID
  it("Finds a record by id from the database", function(done) {

    MarioCharacter.findOne({_id: newCharacter._id}).then(function(result) {
      //Log the value
      console.log(newCharacter._id); // returns 5b277477fd8f6f2c6437e5bc
      console.log(result._id); // returns 5b277477fd8f6f2c6437e5bc

      //Log the type
      console.log(typeof newCharacter._id); // returns object
      console.log(typeof result._id); // returns object

      //Test fails - returns false
      assert(result._id === newCharacter._id);
      done();
    })
  });
```

The solution is to convert both to a string using the `.toString()` method, which means that both types don't seem to be the same, even tough it says object on both of them.

What is it that I don't get here? Are there also subtypes of objects or what?

Comment: Because you are comparing objects. It's javascript and has nothing to do with mongo. `console.log({a:1}  === {a:1})` outputs false because theses are 2 different objects.

Comment: You can read more from [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript) to get a better idea.

Comment: If you really want to compare two BSON type of `_id`, you can do `assert.ok(result._id.equals(newCharacter._id))`, based on [Node.js MongoDB native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/ObjectID.html). You can also go check Node.js MongoDB native driver's source code, you'll see even if you use the method `equals()`, under the hood, it's still doing `id1.toString() === id2.toString()` for you.

Comment: In other words, it's because both objects are referring to different objects, even if they have the same value?

Answer (score 0):

What you see from your `// Log the value` section is actually because Node.js MongoDB native driver has the overridden method `toString()` so that when you do `console.log()`, it'll print the `toString()` result on your console.

See this [MDN post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) talking about `Object.prototype.toString()` and [Node.js MongoDB native driver source code](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/node_modules_bson_lib_bson_objectid.js.html) (line 189-197).

---

Originally, MongoDB's ObjectId is like this:

> ObjectIds are small, likely unique, fast to generate, and ordered. ObjectId values consist of 12 bytes, where the first four bytes are a timestamp that reflect the ObjectId’s creation. Specifically:
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

—— [Introduction to MongoDB > BSON types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid)

Comment: I know why the toString() works and how, but it's more why both Objects, the source of those strings are not the same

Comment: Do you mean `result._id.toString()` and `newCharacter._id.toString()` are not the same? Or `result._id` and `newCharacter._id`?

If it's the latter, then it's because Objects `result._id` and `newCharacter._id` are two different Objects and they don't have the same references, and so they will not be entirely the same thing in JavaScript.